# Solving and checking a first order Bernoulli differential equation: $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + y = y^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Problem:

Solve the following differential equation:
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} + y = y^2 $$

Answer:

Let $v = y^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= -y^{-2} \dfrac{dy}{dx} \\
-y^{-2}\dfrac{dy}{dx} - y^{-1}&= -1 \\
\dfrac{dv}{dx} - v &= -1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to find an  integrating factor. Call the integrating factor $I$.
\begin{align*}
I &= e^{ \int -dx } = e^{-x} \\
e^{-x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} - e^{-x}v  &= -1 \\
e^{-x}v   &= -x + C \\
v &= (c-x)e^x \\
y^{-1} &= (c-x)e^x \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y(c-x)e^x = 1 $$
Now, I wil check my answer.
\begin{align*}
y &= \dfrac{1}{(c-x)e^x} = \left( (c-x)e^x \right) ^{-1}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= (-1)\left(   (c-x)e^x - e^x \right) ^{-2} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= (-1)\left(   (c -1 - x)e^x \right) ^{-2} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \dfrac{ e^{2x} }{ (c-1-x)^2 } \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y &=
 \dfrac{ e^{2x} }{ (c-1-x)^2 } + \left( (c-x)e^x \right) ^{-1}
\end{align*}
I do not see how I can show that:
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} + y = y^2 $$
Hence my solution does not check. Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated soltion which I believe is right. Is it?

Let $v = y^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= -y^{-2} \dfrac{dy}{dx} \\
-y^{-2}\dfrac{dy}{dx} - y^{-1}&= -1 \\
\dfrac{dv}{dx} - v &= -1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to find an  integrating factor. Call the integrating factor $I$.
\begin{align*}
I &= e^{ \int -dx } = e^{-x} \\
e^{-x} \dfrac{dv}{dx} - e^{-x}v  &= -e^{-x} \\
e^{-x}v &= e^{-x} + C \\
v &= 1 + Ce^{x} \\
y^{-1} &= 1 + Ce^{x} \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y = (1 + Ce^{x})^{-1} $$
Now, I wil check my answer.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= (-1)(Ce^x)\left( 1 + Ce^{x}  \right) ^{-2} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= -Ce^x \left( 1 + Ce^{x}  \right) ^{-2} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y &= -Ce^x \left( 1 + Ce^{x}  \right) ^{-2} + (1 + Ce^{x})^{-1} \\
%
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y &= 
 \dfrac{ -Ce^x + 1 + Ce^x}{ \left(  1 + Ce^{x} \right) ^ 2 } \\
%
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y &= \dfrac{ 1}{ \left(  1 + Ce^{x} \right) ^ 2 } \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y &= y^2
\end{align*}
Hence my solution checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the integrating factor, you should have multiplied the entire equation by $I = e^{-x}$. Instead you only multiplied the left. The correct equation is $$e^{-x} \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} - e^{-x} v = e^{-x}.$$

Comment: @kpf is my solution right now?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Alternatively, you can notice the proposed ODE is separable:
\begin{align*}
y' + y = y^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow y' = y^{2} - y \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{y^{2} - y} = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{\left(y - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} - \frac{1}{4}} = 1
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?